# twilio Automatic retry call

Tags: twilio

I use the restful api for voice calls. I used this to call myself. When my phone rings, I don't connect and hang up. After about 20 seconds, I received another call from twilio.

curl 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AccountSid/Calls.json' -X POST --data-urlencode 'To=+1111111' --data-urlencode 'From=+22222' --data-urlencode 'Url=http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml' -u AccountSid:authToken

I hope that when I hang up for the first time, I won't receive a second call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you answer and then hang up or did you decline the call? If you decline the call, the carrier may reattempt the call.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I decline the call. but not every time reattempt the call.